# autoCompletejs: How to fetch keys from backend?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using [autoCompletejs](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/) and want to fetch my list of keys from my backend, but am getting the following error:

autoComplete.js:119 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

My "data" code:

```
    data: {
        src: async () => {
            try {
                // Loading placeholder text
                document.getElementById("autoComplete").setAttribute("placeholder", "Loading...");
                // Fetch External Data Source
                const source = await fetch("/suppliers");
                const data = await source.json();
                console.log(data)
                // Post Loading placeholder text
                document.getElementById("autoComplete").setAttribute("placeholder", autoCompleteJS.placeHolder);
                // Returns Fetched data
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                return error;
            }
        },
        keys: fetch("/keys").then(response => response.json()) //.then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData)
),
        cache:true
    },
```

Values logged:

jsonData:

```
(10) ['263897', '186000', '146294', '278717', '189906', '246548', '130111', '157960', '947854', '138753']
0: "263897"
1: "186000"
2: "146294"
3: "278717"
4: "189906"
5: "246548"
6: "130111"
7: "157960"
8: "947854"
9: "138753"
length: 10
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

data:

```
0: {100058: 'Supplier1', 100211: 'Supplier2', 100476: 'Supplier3', 100986: 'Supplier4' …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the values logged

Comment: Taking a quick look at [the docs](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/configuration?id=keys-required), `keys` doesn't seem to accept a promise, only an array.

Comment: [Disregard, I see the "Function" there.] Thanks for the help. `src` also says it only accepts array but it does accept the promise (the "Async" example demonstrates fetching the data from external source).

Comment: Terrible docs, I know

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `/suppliers` endpoint returns a singleton array (an array with only one item in it) with an object of id / label pairs.

First, singleton arrays are useless. I'd change the backend to return an array of objects but in the meantime, you could map the result to something more useful

```js
data: {
  src: async (query) => {
    const res = await fetch("/suppliers");
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
    }

    // get the first / only array item
    const [data] = await res.json();
    // map to an array of objects with id & label properties
    return Object.entries(data).map(([ id, label ]) => ({ id, label }));
  },
  keys: ["label"],
}
```